# Flutter - using routes in bottomnavigationbar

Tags: flutter

Im trying to navigate to next page via switch index, but it doesn't work.
Does anyone knows how should I use switch case? thank you

Below is my code:

```
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
            title: Text('Home', style: bottomTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 1
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'My Card',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 2
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Watch List',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 3
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Account',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: You can use this [clean code](https://www.fluttertpoint.com/bottom-navigation-in-flutter) and let me know any issue.

Comment: hey dude, any idea how to use switch case?

Comment: You have to create a list and define all the BottomNavigation Classs in that which you want to load. And create a variable for selected Index. Then the on Tap() method of BottomNavigation call a method which hold the index number from the list. Final in the body section use the selected index method. You can understand it from the above link.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code "HomeScreen()" and "NotificationHome()" are the class name to which we need to navigate on tap."

```
class Bottom_Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  const Bottom_Nav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Bottom_NavState createState() => _Bottom_NavState();
}

class _Bottom_NavState extends State<Bottom_Nav> {


  int selectedPage = 0;

  final _pageOptions = [
    const HomeScreen(),
    //const searchHome(),
    NotificationHome(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: _pageOptions[selectedPage],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 30), label: ('Home')),
            
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Badge(
                    badgeContent: Text('3'),
                    child: Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 30)),
                label: ("Notification")),
          ],
          selectedItemColor: bottomBarSelected,
          elevation: 5.0,
          unselectedItemColor: bottomBarNotSelected,
          currentIndex: selectedPage,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment if you have any doubt,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
  
void main() => runApp(MyApp());  
  
/// This Widget is the main application widget.  
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: MyNavigationBar (),  
    );  
  }  
}  
  
class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {  
  MyNavigationBar ({Key key}) : super(key: key);  
  
  @override  
  _MyNavigationBarState createState() => _MyNavigationBarState();  
}  
  
class _MyNavigationBarState extends State<MyNavigationBar> {  
  int _selectedIndex = 0;  
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[  
    Text('Home Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
    Text('Search Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
    Text('Profile Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
  ];  
  
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {  
    setState(() {  
      _selectedIndex = index;
       if(__selectedIndex == 0){
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => secondPage()),
          );
       } else if (__selectedIndex == 1){
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => thirdPage()),
          );
       } else if (__selectedIndex == 2){
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => fourthPage()),
           );
       } else if (__selectedIndex == 3){
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => firstPage()),
           );
       } 
    });  
  }  
  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return Scaffold(  
      appBar: AppBar(  
        title: const Text('Flutter BottomNavigationBar Example'),  
          backgroundColor: Colors.green  
      ),  
      body: Center(  
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),  
      ),  
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(  
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[l̥
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
            title: Text('Home', style: bottomTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: (_selectedIndex == 1)
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'My Card',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: (_selectedIndex == 2)
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Watch List',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: (_selectedIndex == 3)
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Account',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],  
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,  
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,  
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,  
        iconSize: 40,  
        onTap: _onItemTapped,  
        elevation: 5  
      ),  
    );  
  }  
}
```

Replace `secondPage()`, `thirdPage()`, `fourthPage()`, `firstPage()` with class names to which you want to navigate and provide arguments if you have any?..

example: `secondPage('Second Page Title')`

Comment if you have any doubts, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you just add your images or icons instead of my answer Icons :

Go for documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    items:  <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Icon(Icons.home) : Icon(Icons.add),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Icon(Icons.business) : Icon(Icons.person),
        label: 'Business',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: _selectedIndex == 2 ? Icon(Icons.school) : Icon(Icons.close),
        label: 'School'
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
```

Your result screen when your index is 0 -> [image]

Your result screen when your index is 1 -> [image]